# How do I make the position of the text dynamic with resize on an svg element?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a sort of bar chart and I am trying to include data labels. I have drawn the text containing the appropriate values but it doesn't respond well to being resized. Instead of moving with the bar it just stays still till the page is refreshed.

Note that the numbers should be right above the green and red bars:

[image]

```
this.svg.selectAll("text.dataLabels")        
    .data(viewModel.dataPoints)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class","dataLabels")
    .attr({
        y: (dataPoint: BarChartDataPoint) => yScale(<number>dataPoint.value)-BarChart.Config.dataLabelShift.vertical,
        x: (dataPoint: BarChartDataPoint) => xScale(dataPoint.category)+BarChart.Config.dataLabelShift.horizontal
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text((dataPoint: BarChartDataPoint) => <string>dataPoint.value)
    .style({
        'font-family': 'sans-serif',
        'font-weight':'bold',
        'fill': 'grey'
    });
```

Comment: you have to look at why the x-coord of your text is not nicely aligned with the bar. the more to the right the gap increases

Comment: That was after I resized the plot, before resizing the window they are aligned nicely.

Comment: then you haven't updated your `xScale` correctly to use the new SVG sizes

Comment: you need to reread the enter-modify-exit paradigm (join) and think what you do in the `update`

Comment: If that were true then upon resizing I would have issues with the position of the bars as well.

Comment: without the full code it is **very** hard to guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of working directly with the parent svg object and appending a text element directly onto it, instead I create a separate element:

```
 private dataLabels: d3.Selection<SVGElement>;
    this.dataLabels = this.svg
            .append('g')
            .classed('dataLabels',true)
```

I then appended the text elements to a new object:

```
let dataLabelEl = this.dataLabels
                .selectAll('text.dataLabels')
                .data(viewModel.dataPoints);

            dataLabelEl
                .enter()
                .append('text')
                .classed('dataLabels', true);

            dataLabelEl
                .attr({
                    y: (dataPoint) => yScale(<number>dataPoint.value)-BarChart.Config.dataLabelShift.vertical,
                    x: (dataPoint) => xScale(dataPoint.category)+BarChart.Config.dataLabelShift.horizontal
                })
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .text((dataPoint) => <string>dataPoint.value)
                .style({
                    'font-family': 'sans-serif',
                    'font-weight':'bold',
                    'fill': 'grey'
                });
```

This works!

Comment: this only works if you have added the text in another place too

Comment: Can you clarify? I haven't added the text anywhere else

Comment: `dataLabelEl` does not contain the new `text` elements, which version of d3 are you using? (I refer to the d3v4/v5 API)

Comment: Oh I see, I'm working with v3 due to other dependancies that don't work well with the newer versions.

Answer (score -1):

You can set x and y positions of text and it will never make the disturbance in resize [follow the link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text)